# How to format *individual* cells (not via Row or Columns) at time of setting their value?

Tags: c#, winforms

(Corrected - tried to explain it more clearly)

We are showing pathology results from an external supplied data in a DataViewGrid control along with other disparate data from other sources.

This involved adding Columns/Rows and Values on the fly to a DataViewGrid (different dates, different pathology tests names etc).

The dates columns and pathology tests row intersect at a value.

[image]

We want to format the value cell depending on it being high, very high, low, very low which is coming across at the same time in another field associated with the value.

This would be in different BACKGROUND or FOREGROUND Color etc.

e.g GREEN - normal, ORANGE - high, RED - very high etc etc.

How should we do this?

It seems when we set the formatting on the Cell just after the value is added then the format does not seem to change. If we use the DataGridView.CellFormatting Event to do it, then we need to store with the value some sort of marker to now if it is HIGH or VERY HIGH etc. (hence the ** and *) but this want work for other values where we need to show INTERIM, PERFORMED, VALIDATED.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Why do you need "the most efficient" way to do this? How important is efficiency to you? What if you could make it 10 ties as fast, but it would cost you 1000 times as much money to do that?

Comment: My guess would be that you would want to use an event handler such as DataGridView.RowPrePaint. This would be efficient in that at the time of rendering the view you could at the same time alter the rendering of certain cells in each row. Your question is pretty vague as the others have said not much to go on here.

Comment: I have tried to update the information with a more clear exlplanation.